# X11 -- Why is the Emacs logo image missing on the Welcome screen?

Tags: x11

I'm working on developing a new Emacs feature for all three Window systems supported by Emacs, and would like a complete working installation of Emacs built `--with-x --with-x-toolkit=no`.  The welcome screen is not displaying the Emacs logo image that I am used to seeing.  I'm running it on **X11 / XTERM**.

**Q**:  What package do I need from let's say macports or building from source that will enable images on the Welcome screen in Emacs for X?

Here is my configuration:

```
Where should the build process find the source code?    .
What compiler should emacs be built with?               gcc -std=gnu99 -g3 -O2
Should Emacs use the GNU version of malloc?             no
  (The GNU allocators don't work with this system configuration.)
Should Emacs use a relocating allocator for buffers?    no
Should Emacs use mmap(2) for buffer allocation?         no
What window system should Emacs use?                    x11
What toolkit should Emacs use?                          none
Where do we find X Windows header files?                Standard dirs
Where do we find X Windows libraries?                   Standard dirs
Does Emacs use -lXaw3d?                                 no
Does Emacs use -lXpm?                                   yes
Does Emacs use -ljpeg?                                  yes
Does Emacs use -ltiff?                                  yes
Does Emacs use a gif library?                           yes -lgif
Does Emacs use a png library?                           yes -lpng16
Does Emacs use -lrsvg-2?                                yes
Does Emacs use cairo?                                   no
Does Emacs use imagemagick?                             no
Does Emacs support sound?                               no
Does Emacs use -lgpm?                                   no
Does Emacs use -ldbus?                                  yes
Does Emacs use -lgconf?                                 no
Does Emacs use GSettings?                               yes
Does Emacs use a file notification library?             yes (kqueue)
Does Emacs use access control lists?                    yes 
Does Emacs use -lselinux?                               no
Does Emacs use -lgnutls?                                no
Does Emacs use -lxml2?                                  yes
Does Emacs use -lfreetype?                              yes
Does Emacs use -lm17n-flt?                              no
Does Emacs use -lotf?                                   no
Does Emacs use -lxft?                                   yes
Does Emacs directly use zlib?                           yes
Does Emacs have dynamic modules support?                no
Does Emacs use toolkit scroll bars?                     no
Does Emacs support Xwidgets (requires gtk3)?            no
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Does Emacs every display a logo when run in a terminal? It doesn't for me.

Comment: @Tyler -- My impression was that Emacs built `--with-x` creates a GUI version of Emacs, that uses (in part) `xterm.c` and permits me to have fancy things like all `cursor-type` with different colors and so forth.  Although X11/XTERM looks like a terminal, launching Emacs built `--with-x` creates a GUI experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tracked down the problem to the last line of `use-fancy-splash-screens-p`, which erroneously returns `nil`.  If we change the last number from 19 to 17, the Emacs logo appears as expected.  The revised function can be placed in the `.emacs` file and it is detected before the splash screen is displayed.  Here is the open bug report:  http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23074

```lisp
(defun use-fancy-splash-screens-p ()
  "Return t if fancy splash screens should be used."
  (when (and (display-graphic-p)
             (or (and (display-color-p)
          (image-type-available-p 'xpm))
                 (image-type-available-p 'pbm)))
    (let ((frame (fancy-splash-frame)))
      (when frame
  (let* ((img (create-image (fancy-splash-image-file)))
         (image-height (and img (cdr (image-size img nil frame))))
         ;; We test frame-height so that, if the frame is split
         ;; by displaying a warning, that doesn't cause the normal
         ;; splash screen to be used.
         (frame-height (1- (frame-height frame))))
   ;; The original value added to the `image-height' for the test was 19; however,
   ;; that causes the test to fail on X11 by about 1.5 -- so use 17 instead.
    (> frame-height (+ image-height 17)))))))
```